# Can I drill down into all of the properties of an object in javascript at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have an object being passed to a method from a flash object. I would like to be able to view all of the properties in this object a bit like you can do in c# with the 'add watch' feature in visual studio.

Is this possible with javascript and firefox/firebug?

I was thinking of doing a for loop and console.logging the results but what is the best way to iterate the object would I treat it as an array etc?

Any advice much appreciated.
Pete

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        console.log(p + ': ' + obj.p);
    }
}
```

Objects in JavaScript inherit through their prototype, and their prototype can also have a prototype. Using the `hasOwnProperty` method (inherited from Object) checks to see if the property exists on the object you're examining and not associated with its prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Techically, in JS an object is +- an associative array `string->value`, so....

```
for (var key in someObject) {
    // key is a string
    var value = someObject[key];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just use the `for (prop in obj) { }` syntax.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
   console.log(obj[name]);
}
```

in jQuery there is the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method, which allows a callback on each entry:

```
jQuery.each(obj, function(index, prop) {
    console.log(prop);
});
```